# How do I pass around data within an object?

Tags: javascript, oop, d3.js

I have a chart object, with methods `draw` and `update`. [See this (non-working) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXWKD/3/).

`draw` does a lot of things with the object's properties, and at the end, draws a chart. At this point, I am able to define an `update` function, since all the data that was processed by `draw` is there. But then I can't call `update` from outside the scope.

How do I define the `update` method as a completely separate method so I can call it from outside the object, but have it be able to reference data within the `draw` method?

Update: [I've posted some semi-pseudo code](http://jsfiddle.net/MXWKD/3/).

Comment: Some example will be better. Can you post some code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this perhaps:

```
function MyChart(x,y){

   this.draw = function(){
      console.log('draw chart using variables x:' + x + ' y:' + y);

      return {
          update: function(){
               console.log('update chart using variables x:' + x + ' y:' + y);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

usage:

```
 var chart = new MyChart(123,987);
 var drawResult = chart.draw();
 drawResult.update();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/c9TeU/

Comment: Wonderful! I had trouble returning a value from the object (I'm using an ajax response), so I ended up setting the return value as another property on my object - but same idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
function update(obj) {
}

var obj = {
    function draw() {
        update(this); // works
    }
};
```

You might want to read about Javascript [Functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), and about [lexical scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping_and_dynamic_scoping).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give us much information I'll try to guess what you want. I assume you want this:

```
var updateFunction = function(){
   update();
};

return updateFunction();
```

But you can just directly `return update;` In javascript functions can be stored in variables, so if you can pass a variable to outside the scope you can also pass a function

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var TestObject = function () {
    var a, b;
    this.draw = function (aVal, bVal) {
        a = aVal;
        b = bVal;
    }
    this.update = function () {
        console.info("a = " + a + " | b = " + b);
    }
}
```

Then you can call as:

```
var obj = new TestObject();
obj.draw(3, 4);
obj.update();
```

jsfiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/poonia/XAm52/